# Combine $in with $split in mongo

Tags: mongodb

I want to combine $in with $split like in the following example, but it fails saying "$in needs an array". I understand the output of $split is an array so I don't know why it fails. Do you know how to solve it or another way to do it?
Thanks

```
db.mydoc.aggregate([
    {
        '$match': {
            'myid': {
                '$in': {
                    '$split': [
                        '136618,136620,136622',
                        ',',
                    ],
                },
            },
        },
    },
    {
        '$project': { ... },
    },
]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This "fail" is the expected behavior, let's understand why.

We must first take a look at the [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) behavior as specified in the docs:

> $match takes a document that specifies the query conditions. The query syntax is identical to the **read operation query syntax**; i.e. $match does **not accept raw aggregation expressions.** Instead, use a $expr query expression to include aggregation expression in $match.

This means when you use `$match` it uses the query language by default, now the "issue" comes from the difference between the two `$in` operators the [query $in operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) (which is being used) and the [aggregation $in operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/) ( which you assume is being used ).

It is true that `$split` resolves to an array. but `$split` is also an aggregation operator, now I think this case should throw an error but for some reason as you mentioned this behavior just resolves with no results. the aggregation `$in` operator however , does accept raw aggregation expressions.

This means all you have to do is convert your `$match` query to use [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/) so you can use the aggregation version of `$in` within the match, like so:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      $expr: {
        $in: [
          "$myid",
          {
            "$split": [
              "136618,136620,136622",
              ","
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wmco6r_A60-)

Answer (score 0):

@Tom Slabbaert gave a very comprehensive and good answer. Just for sake of completeness, an alternative solution (if you work with Javascript/Mongo shell) is this one:

```
db.mydoc.aggregate([
    {
        '$match': {
            'myid': { '$in': '136618,136620,136622'.split(',') }
        }
    },
    {
        '$project': { ... },
    },
]);
```

Be aware either solutions create an array of strings, i.e. `[ "136618", "136620", "136622" ]`. It does **not match** if your collection has numeric values, e.g. `{ myid: 136618 }`

You may use

```
'136618,136620,136622'.split(',').map(x => NumberInt(x))
```

or

```
{ $map: { input: { "$split": ["136618,136620,136622", ","] }, in: { $toInt: "$$this" } } }
```